# Can any one suggest me the library for timing selector slider as show in wework booking screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4.2

I want to develop a time slider wchich is already implementd on wework app, can anyone tell me about this library or they have made it custom. I have already checked lots of libraries, but I did not find any link regarding for it. It's scrollable and selectable with the 30mins time interval.

I am sharing the link for reference:
[image]

Comment: Better if you add gif of requirement bcz from image we are not cleared.

Comment: Here is the video : https://oneculture.com/slider.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Hey @deepak bhardwaj I find one lib. this is not same to same requirement of your but animation and sliding same you want. please this [Lib](https://github.com/MaximAlien/TimeSliderView)